# netty client design for concurrency

Tags: client-server, netty

Thanks for great library netty and I am using the latest 3.5.8 version. My application design is as below

1. I have a web application which receives the requests from end users (MyWebApp)
2. This web application modifies the data received and constructs a MyBean object and connects to MyServer (built on netty) for processing
3. MyServer executes some business logic and returns a modified MyBean object
4. MyWebApp receives this and handover to end user via JSP

MyServer is working fine and able process requests.

I have observed client delays the request when there are concurrent requests. Though lot of requests are processed in milli seconds there are instances where few requests are delayed. delayed requests take 1-4 minutes sometimes. But I have observed these requests are received by the server very late but processed immediately. So, I can only suspect the client implementation. I tried to implement connection pooling of 'Channel' but requests and responses are mismatched. As both implementations are done by me I have freedom to change the code on both sides. So, I have modified the server messageReceived source code not to close the connection even after it has processed the response. It is now client who opens the channel making the requests and closing the channel after receiving the response.

Ideally I want to use one channel or pool of channels or any other implementation and handle concurrent requests. I felt Netty is very easy for the server implementation but client implementation is not suitable out of the box for my kind of design. if this can be part of netty library itself it would be great

Any ideas would be appreciated.

**My Code is as below on client side**

```
    public class NioConnectorImpl implements ICoreConnector{

private String host;
private int port;
private static ChannelFactory channelFactory;

public NioConnectorImpl(String host, int port){
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
}


@Override
public MyBean processRequest(MyBean bean) {
    return (MyBean) callMyServer(bean);
}


public Object callMyServer(Object requestObject) throws RuntimeException{


    if(channelFactory==null){
        System.out.println("createFactory with 3 Boss Threads and "+Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2+ " Child Threads");
        channelFactory  =  new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(
                Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),3, Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2);
    }

ClientBootstrap bootstrap = new ClientBootstrap(channelFactory);

    // Set up the event pipeline factory.
    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new MyChannelPipelineFactory(requestObject));
    //Connection timeOut for initial connection...
    bootstrap.setOption("connectTimeoutMillis", 10000);
    bootstrap.setOption("tcpNoDelay", true);
    bootstrap.setOption("keepAlive", true);

    ChannelFuture connectFuture = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));

// Wait until the connection is made successfully.
    Channel channel = connectFuture.awaitUninterruptibly().getChannel();

    // Get the handler instance to retrieve the answer.
    MyChannelHandler handler = (MyChannelHandler) channel.getPipeline().getLast();

    Object  object = handler.getObjectBean();

    channel.close().awaitUninterruptibly();

    //bootstrap.releaseExternalResources();
    //channelFactory.releaseExternalResources();

return object;

}

@Override
public void safeReleaseResources() {
    System.out.println("Releasing External Resources::::::::::::");
    if(channelFactory!=null)
    channelFactory.releaseExternalResources();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000L);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

**MyChannelHandler code**

```
    public class MyChannelHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler{

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyChannelHandler.class.getName());
    private final Object object;
    final BlockingQueue<Object> answer = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Object>();

    public MyChannelHandler(Object object) {
        this.object= object;
    }

    public Object getObjectBean() {
        boolean interrupted = false;
        for (;;) {
            try {
                Object object = answer.take();
                if (interrupted) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                return object;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                interrupted = true;
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) {
        sendObject(e);
    }



    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final MessageEvent e) {
        if (e.getMessage() != null) {
            // Offer the answer after closing the connection.
            e.getChannel().close().addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) {
                    boolean offered = answer.offer((Object) e.getMessage());
                    assert offered;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING,"Naga: Unexpected exception from downstream.",e.getCause());
        e.getChannel().close();
    }

    private void sendObject(ChannelStateEvent e) {
        Channel channel = e.getChannel();
       if(channel.isWritable()) channel.write(object);
    }
}
```

**MyServer code**

```
     public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {


    Object object = MyServerController().handleRequest(e.getMessage(), e.getRemoteAddress().toString());

    final ChannelFuture future =  e.getChannel().write(object);
         future.addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {
                public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture f) {
                    Channel ch = future.getChannel();
                    //ch.close(); // expect client closes the connection
                }
         });
}
```